# НАМОКШИЙ: причастие или прилагательное?

Tags: прилагательные, причастия

Не нашёл в словарях (кроме Викисловаря в котором указано, что это *причастие*).

Всё-таки, **намокший** — причастие или прилагательное?

Как по мне, так это отглагольное прилагательное. Хочется услышать ваше мнение.

Comment: Хочется прежде всего услышать вашу аргументацию. Иначе, если вам человек пять ответят в таком же стиле "я считаю, что причастие, а я - что прилагательное",то что делать будем? Референдум устраивать?

Comment: Мой аргумент, что частотно употребляется в качестве определения, без зависимых слов и оттенка протяжённости во времени.

Answer (score 6):

Думаю, что промокший  - **это причастие**, **так как нет явных признаков перехода в прилагательное**. Причастие здесь обозначает процессуальный признак предмета как завершившееся действие.

Например:  Лицо её было искажено болезненной гримасой, а **намокшие** пряди волос прилипли ко лбу. [М. А. Булгаков. Крещение поворотом (1925)]

Примеры перехода причастий в прилагательные часто связан с переносным значением слова: испуганный олень - испуганный вид, надутый шар - надутый слог, избитый прохожий - избитая тема.  В то же время отсутствие зависимых слов не считается явным признаком перехода.

**Из Интернета** [Причастия и отглагольные прилагательные | studfiles.ru](http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/2839934/)

**В различных группах** причастий развитие качественных значений и утрата глагольности при образовании прилагательных протекают неравномерно. **Так, действительные причастия в меньшей мере способны образовать прилагательные, чем причастия страдательные.**
**Действительные причастия прошедшего времени, особенно возвратные (на -ся), являются более стойкими в отношении сохранения глагольности и реже образуют прилагательные.** Наличие частицы-приставки не- у причастий придает им ярко выраженный оттенок возможного качества и облегчает образование прилагательных (неудавшийся актер, незадавшееся предприятие).

Comment: Согласен. К тому же в Грамматическом словаре русского  языка Зализняка намокший - причастие.

Answer (score 3):

**Намокший** - как и большинство подобных слов - с грамматической точки зрения может быть и тем и другим. Определяется местом и ролью в предложении.

- *У него была **намокшая голова***. Скорее прилагательное (результат важен, т. е. качество, не процесс и нет зависимых слов).
- *У него была **голова**, сильно **намокшая от проливного дождя***. По законам трактуется как причастие (зависимые слова и процесс-состояние).

Хотя, если разобраться, принципиальной разницы в грамматической функции слова тут нет.

Вообще современная модель грамматики такова, что эти части речи зачастую вообще неотличимы друг от друга. Требование строго их различения — скорее дань традиции. С семантической же точки зрения все причастия от непереходных глаголов действительно наиболее близки к отглагольным прилагательным, поскольку выпадает одно наиболее важное и частое зависимое слово (объект действия). Но этого явно мало, чтобы делать далеко идущие выводы. В классической грамматике такие слова однозначно трактуются как причастия. Которые, впрочем, как уже сказал, легко становятся прилагательными.

Comment: "Требование строго их различения — скорее дань традиции"

А как же различие в написании н/нн?

Answer (score 0):

О том, что это причастие, говорит суффикс -ш-, с помощью которого можно определить залог (действительный) и время (прошедшее).